# Can I fix/replace my Falcon on Halo Reach Alexandria level?

Tags: halo-reach

I'm playing on Legendary, and my ride is already full of holes after the first sub-mission. It does not look like it is supposed to last the whole level - those Banshees keep coming.

Is there a way to fix my aircraft? Is there a replacement hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stand on the ground somewhere (maybe at a landing pad-esque area only) and press **down on the D-pad**, you will "summon an evac".  For me, I was warped to the beginning of the mission where a fresh Falcon flew in.

I think your new falcon could be shot down by the enemies in this time, as there was a banshee shooting mine.  It lived and I blew up the banshee, but I don't know if it can blow up the evac and what happens if it does.

Comment: Thanks. It's down, not right, but is still saved my hide.

Comment: And *hold* down arrow for MCC pc keyboard/mouse (it's not mentioned in the configuration settings at all), and make sure to destroy your existing falcon first. My evac refused to land..so I had to do the rest of legendary..very carefully.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to "fix" aircraft in Halo. Unlike the Battlefield series, once your vehicle is damaged, there is no way to restore its health.

I do not know if there are replacements but an outside the box answer is to steal a Banshee :p